# list.files - exclude folder

Tags: r, regex

I want to use R's list.files function to find all text files in a folder and in its subfolders. However, I would like to exclude all files that are in one subfolder, let's say it contains unfinished work which is not ready for the things I use the other files for. Structure is like this:

```
- folder
 |- subfolder_1_good_stuff
 |- subfolder_2_good_stuff
 |- subfolder_3_good_stuff
 |- subfolder_4_unfinished_stuff
```

So "folder" would be my working directory.

I would now use:

```
list.files(path=".", pattern=".txt", recursive=TRUE)
```

But what should I add to "path" expression in order to exclude folder with unfinished stuff. This folder name will not be present in any filenames, if that makes some difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use regex - `grepl` to exclude:

```
# find all ".txt" files
myfiles <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = ".txt",
                      full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

# exclude unfinished stuff
myfilesfinished <- myfiles[ !grepl("unfinished_stuff", myfiles) ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Building upon @zx8754's answer, just with `tidyverse` approach using `%>%`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

list.files(path=".", pattern=".txt", full.names = TRUE, recursive=TRUE) %>%
   stringr::str_subset(., "unfinished_stuff", negate = TRUE)
```